# How to conditionally connect between a custom made class and one of two UI image during run?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, iboutlet

There is three main points to understand the question:

1- There's a custom made class "Monster" that inherits from UIImageView superclass

2-There're two images(game characters) in the UI that user has to choose between them

3-According to this choice, one of the two images will appear and the other will be staying hidden

-Each of the images is connected to the UI with its own image

```
@IBOutlet weak var rockMonster: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var fireMonster: UIImageView!

var activeCharacter: Monster!
```

-According to which button is pressed the Monster object will carry the result which differs in the image and the type of character

```
@IBAction func fireMonsterChoosed(sender: AnyObject) {
    activeCharacter = Monster (typ: "fireMonster", frame: fireMonster.frame)
    activeCharacter.hidden = false

@IBAction func rockMonsterchoosed(sender: AnyObject) {
    activeCharacter = Monster (typ: "rockMonster", frame: rockMonster.frame)
    activeCharacter.hidden = false
```

-Now, the activeCharacter var even after equalizing its .frame property with the one of the chosen character, it still has no control on the image so it's not connected with the UI

```
activeCharacter.hidden = false //No images appear
```

Q : I need to give activeCharacter var the control over these images in UI after the initialization I make in each IBAction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using two different image views?  Why not simply assign the correct UIImage depending on the monster type?

Comment: @Paulw11 how it can be done during the run?

Comment: You can use `UIImage(named:)`

Comment: okay fair enough....but what about the constraints? The methode I am using allows me to add more images (game characters) by simply just initializing them

Comment: You don't seem to have separated your data from your view.  You only need a single `UIImageView`.  You can have any number of different monsters defined by your data.  You simply load the correct image into the `UIImageView` depending on the monster chosen.  Your `Monster` class probably doesn't need to inherit form UIImageView.  It is simply a class with properties, one of which is a `UIImage`.  This image can be assigned to a `UIImageView` as required.

Comment: but that means I have to choose equal size images so the constraints fits on all of them as it's only one UIImageView

Comment: You would typically want to keep the sizes somewhat similar sizes anyway for layout reasons, but you can modify the constraints of the imageview at run time.  To answer your original question, you can also create a property of your Monster class that returns the active `UIImageView`

Comment: That's my backup solution but I need to know if there's a way to make a connection like a refrence to that image during runtime.

Comment: If you want to persist with the monster being a subclass of `UIImageView` then your `rockMonster` and `fireMonster` properties should be of type `Monster`, not `UIImageView` and you need to set the image view custom class in your storyboard scene.  You will also assign the image in the storyboard scene and then you just say `activeCharacter = fireMonster` or `activeCharacter = rockMonster` in the `@IBAction` method